# How to decompress the gz files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Wanted to know if there is any hadoop command to decompress the gz file

sitting on HDFS and display the content to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

Just use text command

> hdfs dfs -text file.gz

Hadoop knows how to detect gzip files and uncompresses it for you

Comment: interesting. how this compares to fuse answer below? I guess it might be slower because gunzipping is done on a hadoop server, so you transfer uncompressed data. with hdfs fuse mount and running gunzip on that mount, you transfer only compressed data. Also your answer does not help if you need to save decompressed file back to hdfs (just shell redirect to a file wouldn't do as you may not have enough local filesystem space).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily by:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /path/to/file.gz | zcat
```